# len(nlp.vocab) showing only 486, how I can load total vocab 57852

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have installed Spacy using conda.

`conda install -c conda-forge spacy`

`python -m spacy download en`

And installed version was

[image]

[image]

`import spacy`

`nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`

`doc = nlp(u"Let's visit St. Louis in the U.S. next year.")`

`len(doc)`

`len(doc.vocab)`

`len(nlp.vocab)`

**len(doc.vocab) and  len(nlp.vocab)  showing only 486.**

**How can we load it to show 57852.**

[image]

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, you have downloaded the **small** spaCy model. You can download either the medium model (91 MB) or the large model (789 MB) via these commands:

```
# medium
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md

# large
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

To use any one of them, just load it as you did with the small model:

```
# medium
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

# large
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
```

This [link](https://spacy.io/models/en) contains all spaCy English models and how to installthem.

Comment: Hi @Anwarvic, Now I have loaded **Large model**, now len(nlp.vocab) showing as 1340242. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Glad, I could help :)